# why passing an argument to lua class method get nill

Tags: lua, parameter-passing

I have a method that builds a Tree from a parent list pointer in lua.
In particular I have this **lua table**

```
parents = {2,3,13,5,12,7,11,9,10,11,12,13,14,0}
```

Along with two functions:

**Function 1 (creates the node):**

```
function create_node(parent, i, created, root)
  if created[i] ~= nil then
        return
  end
    print(i)
--    print(parent)
--  Create a new node and set created[i]
    local new_node = Tree()
    new_node.idx = i
    created[i] = new_node


--    If 'i' is root, change root pointer and return
    if parent[i] == 0 then
       root[1] = created[i] -- root[1] denotes root of the tree

       return
    end

--    If parent is not created, then create parent first
    if created[parent[i]] == nil  then
        create_node(parent, parent[i], created, root )
    end
    print(i)

--    Find parent pointer
    local p = created[parent[i]]
    print (p)

    if #p.children <=2 then
      print(p.idx)
      print(created[i].idx)
      p.add_child(created[i])
    end

end
```

**Function 2 (creates the tree recursively):**
*I have stopped the loop at one to test the first path from leaf to root i.e 1-2-3-13-14*

```
function read_postorder_parent_tree(parents)
    n = #parents

--    Create and array created[] to keep track 
--    of created nodes, initialize all entries as None
    created = {}

    root = {}
    for i=1, 1 do
        create_node(parents, i, created, root)
    end
    return root[1]
end
```

The `create_note` method uses the below `Tree` class:

```
local Tree = torch.class('Tree')

function Tree:__init()
  self.parent = nil
  self.num_children = 0
  self.children = {}
end

function Tree:add_child(c)

  print(c)
  c.parent = self
  self.num_children = self.num_children + 1
  self.children[self.num_children] = c
end
```

Everything works fine but when I call `p.add_child(created[i])` the argument is `nil` why? (why `c` is `nil`?) I have already checked that `created[i]` and `p` are not `nil`. How can i solve this and/or why this happening?

This is the error that I get:

```
./Tree.lua:16: attempt to index local 'c' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    ./Tree.lua:16: in function 'add_child'
    main.lua:120: in function 'create_node'
    main.lua:109: in function 'create_node'
    main.lua:109: in function 'create_node'
    main.lua:109: in function 'create_node'
    main.lua:134: in function 'read_postorder_parent_tree'
    main.lua:153: in function 'main'
    main.lua:160: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...3rto/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00405d50
```

Comment: provide the actual error message, not your interpretation.

Comment: @Piglet i post it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define a function in an object-oriented way, you must also call it in the same way.

```
function Tree:add_child(c)
```

This declares a function in an object-oriented way using the *colon operator*. To help you understand what that means, it can be rewritten like this:

```
Tree.add_child = function(self, c)
```

As you can see, an implicit `self` parameter is created to reflect the object the function was called on. However, you call the function via the standard way:

```
p.add_child(created[i])
```

Now you can see that what you really did was pass `created[i]` as `self`, not as `c`, which then of course happens to be nil. The standard way to call such a function is also via the colon operator:

```
p:add_child(created[i])
```

This implicitly passes `p` as `self` to the actual function, and now `p` will contain the actual argument.